# LEFT JOIN shortcuts are causing error when using OOP and PDO

Tags: php, mysql, left-join

Here's my code:

**Mysql table:**

**group**

| id | name | permission |

**users**

| id | name | username | group |

```
$sql = 'SELECT * FROM `users` u LEFT JOIN `groups` g ON g.id = u.group WHERE u.name = ? OR u.id = ?;
```

Since I have columns named the same, when I try to set the names in php, it is giving me wrong data (from groups to be exact)

```
'ID'            => isset($user->data()->u.id) ? escape($user->data()->u.id) : NULL,
'NAME'          => isset($user->data()->u.name) ? escape($user->data()->u.name) : NULL,
'USERNAME'      => isset($user->data()->u.username) ? escape($user->data()->u.username) : NULL,
```

It is giving me error: `Fatal error: Cannot use isset() on the result of an expression (you can use "null !== expression" instead) in C:\aaa\lang\en\common.lang.php on line 9`

How can I write an SQL in a way where it doesn't interfier with my objects else where?

PS: I'm aware that I can rename my columns, but it will take me forever and I'm sure there's got to be a better way.

-Thanks

Comment: Are you sure that's what line #9 of `common.lang.php` looks like? The error message doesn't seem to marry up with the code. What does `$user->data()` return?

Comment: You right Phil, I originally had u.id and u.name which triggered that error, I fixed it before I posted a question. Anyways, I put it back, just to make the source of the error a little more obvious.

Comment: You must not prefix the object properties with the table name. Just use the field name : `isset($user->data()->id)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sounds like you need to stop using `SELECT *` (always a good option IMO) and use column aliases where appropriate. For example...

```
SELECT u.id AS user_id, u.name AS user_name, u.username,
       g.id AS group_id, g.name AS group_name -- and so on
```

As for your error message, you are using the concatenation operator (`.`). That results in an expression which cannot be used in `isset()`. With the above aliases and assuming that `$user->data()` returns the results via `PDO::FETCH_OBJ`, you can use...

```
'ID' => isset($user->data()->user_id) ? escape($user->data()->user_id) : null,
// etc
```

If you **really** don't want to select each column, providing aliases where appropriate, the only other option I can think of would be to create a *view*, eg

```
CREATE VIEW users_and_groups AS
SELECT u.id AS user_id, u.name AS user_name, u.username,
       g.id AS group_id, g.name AS group_name -- and any other columns you need
FROM users u
LEFT JOIN groups g ON g.id = u.`group`
```

Then you can simply `SELECT * FROM users_and_groups`.

Comment: This would work fine, but I'm actually selecting all the columns. If I use what you've suggested I will have to write all of the columns. Is there a way where I can only overwrite columns with the same name, but the rest will be selected the standard way? Ie: SELECT u.id AS user_id, * FROM something like that?

Comment: @Timur I've added an alternative but I still think `SELECT *` is just lazy. You might also be interested in reading this - [Why is SELECT * considered harmful?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3639861/why-is-select-considered-harmful)

Comment: Thanks for the tip, phil. I ended up using your first suggestion.